# How to select and change value of table cell with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

How do I change the content of the cell containing the 'c' letter in the HTML sample using jQuery?

```
<table id="table_header">
<tr>
   <td>a</td>
   <td>b</td>
   <td>c</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
$("td:contains('c')").html("new");
```

or, more precisely `$("#table_headers td:contains('c')").html("new");`

and maybe for reuse you could create a function to call

```
function ReplaceCellContent(find, replace)
{
    $("#table_headers td:contains('" + find + "')").html(replace);
}
```

Comment: Isn't there the way to reference the *third column* instead of the slow string search?

Comment: sure, you can do `$("#table_headers td:eq(2)").html("new");`

Comment: or `$("#table_headers td:last").html("new");`

Answer (score 17):

Using [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) you can target the third cell in the table:

```
$('#table_header td').eq(2).html('new content');
```

If you wanted to target *every* third cell in each row, use the [`nth-child-selector`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

```
$('#table_header td:nth-child(3)').html('new content');
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching).

Depending on how you get that td, you can either give it an id:

```
<td id='cell'>c</td>
```

and then use:

```
$("#cell").text("text");
```

Or traverse to the third cell of the first row of table_header, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to change the column value in a specific row. Thanks to above answers
and after some searching able to come up with below,

```
var dataTable = $("#yourtableid");
var rowNumber = 0;  
var columnNumber= 2;   
dataTable[0].rows[rowNumber].cells[columnNumber].innerHTML = 'New Content';
```

Answer (score 2):

i was looking for changing second row html and you can do cascading selector

```
$('#tbox1 tr:nth-child(2) td').html(11111)
```

Answer (score -4):

You can do this :

```
<table id="table_header">
<tr>
   <td contenteditable="true">a</td>
   <td contenteditable="true">b</td>
   <td contenteditable="true">c</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: They wanted to know how to change the value using jQuery, not what changes they should make to the XML.