# Jquery to manipulate Table cell

Tags: jquery, tablecell

Fefering to this example: [Changing table cell contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737476/changing-table-cell-contents).

How is it possible to change a table cell if their is more then 1 column and no content in the cell.

For example change the 3rd cell in the 2nd column?

```
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Daten 1</th>
    <th scope="col">Daten 2</th>
    <th scope="col">Daten 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="A1">1</td>
    <td id="B1">1</td>
    <td id="C1">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="A2">2</td>
    <td id="B2">2</td>
    <td id="C2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="A3">3</td>
    <td id="B3">3</td>
    <td id="C3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="A4">4</td>
    <td id="B4">4</td>
    <td id="C4">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wrong idea : ID must be unique

Comment: $('#data tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(3)')

Comment: just an error by copy and paste don't mind

Comment: @TheMasta you should take a moment and pick an answer to your question if one of them solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `:nth-child` selector. Much like the CSS selector it's based on, `nth-child(i)` takes 1-based indexes.

```
$('table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3)').html('changed');
```

[Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Soviut/zUC74/) demonstrating it.

Answer (score 0):

To Select **3rd cell in 2nd column** this means You have to select 3rd row first and then pick its second column. Try this jquery selector on your table

```
$('#data tr:nth-child(3) td::nth-child(2))
```

or even better

```
$('#data').find('tr:nth-child(3)').find('td::nth-child(2)')
```

Even This might not be the best way to get the table cell.

**Suggestion**: If you can give some id based on their index to each table cell, then its easy to compute the id and use `$('#cellId_23')`.

Each cell will have its unique ID. For example: Cell(1,1) can have id like cell_11 and Cell(1,2) will have cell_12 and so on.

This will be much better performant than above two selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the eq() method to find the td starting from 0 index.

`var value = $('#table_id').find("td").eq(5).html();`

Answer (score 0):

something like,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var t = document.getElementById('data');
    jQuery(t.rows[1].cells[2]).text('1st row last C'); 
    jQuery(t.rows[2].cells[2]).text('2nd row last C'); 

});
```

Live [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jobinjose01/LnJ5F/)

Comment: $(function() { }); is the same as the old $(document).ready(function() {});